# How can i print a method that return a refrence variable of calculation of area?

Tags: java, object, reference, return-type

I'm learning object and i'm trying diffrent things to learn that. I've writen 2 method one of them return's an int and it works as i want. But other one is tuffer bc i'm doing something wrong it gives strange numbers. Could you please help me how can i write Box calculateArea2?(I looked at getter and setter but we did not learn those things yet). Here is my code;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box box1 = new Box();
    Box box2 = new Box();
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a length and width");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(str);

    box1.length = input.nextInt();
    box1.width = input.nextInt();

    int BoxsArea = calculateArea(box1); // calculate box1
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " First Box's area is: "+BoxsArea );

    String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a length and width");
    input = new Scanner(str2);

    box2.length = input.nextInt();
    box2.width = input.nextInt();

    Box box3 = new Box();
    calculateArea2(box2); // Calculate box 2

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Second Box's area is: "+box3 );

}

public static int calculateArea(Box k){
    return k.length* k.width;
}


public static Box calculateArea2(Box k){
    Box c = new Box();
    c.area = c.length*c.area;
    return c;
}
```

}

```
class Box{
int length;
int width;
int area;
```

}

Comment: Why do you have a string as a parameter in the constructor of the scanner (`new Scanner(str)`)? Anyways, your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Override the Box class's `public String toString()` method so that when you pass a Box object into the println method, it will display text that makes sense, that tells you the Box objects state (its length, width and area).

Comment: @Gendarme Bc i want to repeat what i know and it helps to remmember old lessons,

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Could you please explain why do i need to Ovirride toString method? Why default toString methods is not good enough to write my object, why does that  method need something like this ;  public String toString(){
  return ""+area;}

Answer (score 0):

`c.area = c.length*c.area;` should be `c.area = k.length*k.area;`

And, to write the object in your console logs, you should implement `toString()` method for Box like this:

```
@Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("Box [length=");
            builder.append(length);
            builder.append(", width=");
            builder.append(width);
            builder.append(", area=");
            builder.append(area);
            builder.append("]");
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

You will be able to write the object in console using `box.toString()` or even with `box` then. Different IDEs provide the capability to generate toString() implementation looking at the class.

Comment: It is still giving memory of location of object :/

Comment: Updated my answer.